# How can I provide a custom function, depending on major-mode variables, right after the startup of Spacemacs?

Tags: elisp, startup, org-mode, custom-function, spacemacs

I recently started to write some elisp code, mostly to customize my spacemacs -> absolute beginner. Although there are a many different sources of "how to customize..." around, I still am confused about the following.

The situation is that I would like to have a custom function ready at startup of spacemacs, but this function is depending on some major mode variables. What is the best way to achieve that, without having to open a file triggering loading this major mode first?

A specific example:
I would like to access (with completion) my org-agenda-files interactively, so I wrote this function

```
  (defun my/org-agenda-find-file(file-path)
    (interactive (list
                  (completing-read "Choose agenda file: " org-agenda-files)))
    (find-file file-path)
    )

# Binding 
 (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "oof" #'my/org-agenda-find-file)
```

and put it in an custom my_org_config.el, which gets loaded in .spacemacs/dotspaceamcs/user-conifg().
So far so good, works as expected if org-mode has been loaded at least once before.

In case of a freshly started spacemacs, trying to use my function, I get the error that
"org-agenda-files" is not existing. So it seems that "org-agenda-files" is set during the loading of org-mode.

One working solution is to add the "require 'org" statement before my function, but I'm not sure if this is a very good way of handling that.

```
(require 'org)
(defun my/org-agenda-find-file(file-path)
  (interactive (list
                (completing-read "Choose agenda file: " org-agenda-files)))
  (find-file file-path)
  )
```

Is there a better way of doing that, maybe through a key-word or a call within the function itself, or is this one of the cases where require and spacemacs go together fine :)?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `(require 'org)` to the top-level, as you did, is one method to ensure that the org feature is loaded when you call your function. I think there is nothing wrong with it except that the feature will be loaded even though you don't use it, unnecessarily delaying the startup.

You can alternatively put `(require 'org)` inside your function to prevent the feature from being loaded if not needed, as shown in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html).

```
(defun my/org-agenda-find-file (file-path)
  (require 'org)
  ...)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I did not put it inside the function to not delay the function call itself, but I guess that is just negligible.

Comment: Since the second part of your solution seems not to work for interactive functions, I posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286103/is-it-possible-to-load-modes-in-interactive-functions-before-the-interactive-pro).